# Different distance on Xamarin and Google maps

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.forms

I am getting different distances on Google maps and when I calculate using CalculateDistance() method in Xamarin. How to calculate the driving distance in Xamarin? Is there any method that I can use to calculate Maps distance in c# / Xamarin?

The below code calculates the distance between two locations. But it is different to driving distance on Google maps.

```
var location = new Location(21.705723, 72.998199);
var otherLocation = new Location(22.3142, 73.1752);
double distance =  location.CalculateDistance(otherLocation,DistanceUnits.Kilometers);
```

Comment: This code does direct point to point, but you say Google Maps is "driving distance" which is going to include turns etc. Why would you expect them to be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never get the same distance which is displayed in Google Maps, As the Google Maps doesn't show the shortest distance but it sees a numerous other things which will make the distance in car different from distance traveled in bike or by walk. Also, the distance  today may be different from yesterday due to some road being closed for repair, etc..

So, the only way to achieve the Google Map's intelligent distance calculation is to use its own API

**1. Create Requests to the Google Maps API by yourself**

You can just send HTTP-Requests to the google maps API and then work with the results.
You could use [WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx) to forge requests to the google api. You need a  [Maps API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) for that.

---

Check out the [Google Maps Api Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/) (under Web Service APIs) which lists all the request parameters and example responses.

**C# example**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string origin = "Oberoi Mall, Goregaon";
    string destination = "Infinity IT Park, Malad East";
    string url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" +
 origin + "&destinations=" + destination + "&key=CKzaDyBE188Pm_TZXCC_x5Gt67FU5vC9mEPw1";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        using (WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new 
            StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                DataSet dsResult = new DataSet();
                dsResult.ReadXml(reader);
                duration.Text = dsResult.Tables["duration"].Rows[0]["text"].ToString();
                distance.Text = dsResult.Tables["distance"].Rows[0]["text"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```